# Create a categorical variable

Tags: r, categorical-data, recode

I want to categorized one variable with the next conditionals:

0 - 4: "fail"
5 - 7: "good"
8 - 10: "excellent"
None of the above: NA

I tried using the recode function

The values of variable is numeric

```
segur <- data$segur
```

Created a new variable using recode

```
dt1 <- recode(segur, "c(0,4)='suspenso';c(5, 7)='aceptable';c(8,10)='excelente'; else='NA'")
dt1
```

How can I fix?

Comment: try the `cut` or `ifelse` functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `factor` in base `R`

**Data:**

```
# set random seed
set.seed(1L)
# without any NA
x1 <- sample(x = 1:10, size = 20, replace=TRUE)
# with NA
x2 <- sample(x = c(1:10, NA), size = 20, replace=TRUE)
```

**Code:**

```
# without any NA
as.character(factor(x1, levels = c(0:10), labels = c(rep("fail", 5), rep("good", 3), rep("excellent", 3)), exclude=NA))

# with NA    
as.character(factor(x2, levels = c(0:10), labels = c(rep("fail", 5), rep("good", 3), rep("excellent", 3)), exclude=NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use `cut` like below

```
cut(segur, c(0, 4, 7, 10), labels = c("fail", "good", "excellent"))
```

**Example**

```
> segur
 [1]  6  1  4 -2 -1 10  8  0  5  9

> cut(segur, c(0, 4, 7, 10), labels = c("fail", "good", "excellent"))
 [1] good      fail      fail      <NA>      <NA>      excellent excellent
 [8] <NA>      good      excellent
Levels: fail good excellent
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the [fmtr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=fmtr) package.  You can create a categorical format using the `value` and `condition` functions, and then apply the format to the numeric data using the `fapply` function.  Here is an example:

```
library(fmtr)

# Create sample data
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
ID  segur
1      0
2      8
3      5
4      11
5      7')

# Create format
fmt <- value(condition(x >= 0 & x <=4, "fail"),
             condition(x >= 5 & x <=7, "good"),
             condition(x >= 8 & x <= 10, "excellent"),
             condition(TRUE, NA))

# Apply categorization
df$segur_cat <- fapply(df$segur, fmt)

# View results
df
#   ID segur segur_cat
# 1  1     0      fail
# 2  2     8 excellent
# 3  3     5      good
# 4  4    11      <NA>
# 5  5     7      good
```